# Какие параметры Instances и rps_schedule нужно выбирать , чтобы при небольших затратах памяти обстрелять машину скажем с 100 000 rps?

Tags: яндекс-танк

Указываю схему нагрузки `line(10,5000,10m)`, при этом танк подсвечивает в консоли красным число инстансов. Поставил 1000 - ничего не изменилось. Поставил больше - перестало хватать памяти.

На виртуалке 2800 Мб, можно найти с 6500Мб, но не думаю, что это мне поможет.

Какие параметры `Instances` и `rps_schedule` нужно выбирать, чтобы при небольших затратах памяти обстрелять машину скажем с 100 000 rps?

Answer (score 2):

Число инстансов рассчитывается исходя из требуемой нагрузки танком:
допустим, на 5000 rps сервер в среднем отвечает за 250мс. Это значит что танку необходимо иметь не меньше чем 1250 инстансов для обеспечения требуемой нагрузки.
Логика такая: при среднем времени запроса 250мс, один инстанс за одну секунду может отправить и получить ответ для 4х запросов. Делим требуемые 5000 rps на 4 запроса обрабатываемые одним инстансом, получаем 1250. Если же сервер отвечает в среднем за 3 секунды, то очевидно, что необходимо иметь уже больше 15000 инстансов: в первую секунду у танка будут заняты первые 5к инстансов, которые отправят запросы и будут заняты ожиданием ответа, во вторую секунду заняты окажутся следующие 5к итд. На 4ю секунду теста освободится часть из первых 5к инстансов которые можно будет занять снова.

Уменьшить объем потребляемой памяти можно указав фантому выделять меньше памяти под вычитку ответа опциями `phantom_http_*`(https://yandextank.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration.html?#options). При этом необходимо чтобы ответ влезал в это ограничение, иначе вместо корректного завершения сессий, танк будет слать RST преждевременно закрывая соединение.
Возможно здесь пригодится, если еще не указан, заголовок в запросах `[Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate]` для уменьшения размера ответа.